# Database design and query

Tags: sql, mysql, database, architecture

I have a requirement to have a number of sub-topics per main Topic.  And every sub-topic needs to be able to have n number of comments.

I need to have database tables to represent this structure and then query for it to get the list of sub-topics, and for every subtopic get all the comments that belong to it.  I also have to have a way to know when I reached the end of the comments for every subitopic.

Could someone please advise on best design/query for this?

I use MySQL.

Thank you very much!
- Alex

Comment: I feel like my homework sensor is going off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this database design might work:

```
TOPIC
id
name

TOPIC_HAS_TOPIC
id
parentId
childId

COMMENTS
id
comment
topicId
```

Answer (score 1):

Tables needed: 
Topic 
SubTopic (has a parent key pointing back to parent topic)
Comment (has a parent key pointing to the parent sub topic)

Then for a given subtopic, just select all comments with that sub topic key.

Answer (score 0):

You could design it like this:

```
|Topic| -1----*- |SubTopic| -1----*- |Comments|
```

(EDIT:The asterisk seems to mark for italics. So please ignore the color difference)

i.e., a 1-to-many relation from topic to subtopic and another 1-many from subtopic to comments

You could have surrogate primary keys per table:

```
Create Table Topic (topic_id int auto_increment, primary key(topic_id),...)
```

similarly subtopic_id for Subtopic and a foreign key to topic and so on for Comments.

Getting all the comments for a particular topic could be like: (assuming a text attribute for the Comments table (probably a TEXT data type?))

```
select comment.text from comments
join suptopic using(subtopic_id)
join topic using (topic_id)
where topic_id = 1;
```

(*join* is the same as *inner join* and '*using*' is applicable ONLY if the 'join-column' shares the same name, else the syntax differs).

Comment: Assumption: Assuming that a single subtopic belongs to only one topic (else go with arex's schema and you'll just have extra joins in your query)